# Ruby, waiting for callbacks

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm writing a mpd client using the [ruby-mpd](https://github.com/archSeer/ruby-mpd/) library. It has callback driven event listeners but I don't know how to wait for a callback to be executed.o

```
require 'ruby-mpd'

puts "started new thread"
mpd = MPD.new('localhost', '6600', callbacks: true)

# MPD#connect and MPD#disconnect fire the `:connection` event.
mpd.on(:connection) do |connection|
  if connection
    puts 'connected...'
  else
    puts 'disconnected'
  end
end

mpd.connect
```

If I run this line by line in IRB `connected` will be printed after `mpd.connect` but if I run it as a script it exits immediately after calling connect (before the callback gets called?)
Adding a `sleep` call at the end of the file doesn't help either.

How can I make this script never exit and wait for a kill signal from the user?

Ok, I looked at the how ruby-mpd implements callbacks. It spawns a thread which loops over a block that updates a status object. If the object changes it emits an event.

I think my initial example missed the change in the `connection` attribute so that even was never fired.

```
require 'ruby-mpd'

mpd = MPD.new('localhost', '6600', callbacks: true)

mpd.on(:connection) do
  puts 'connected...'
end

mpd.on(:state) do |state|
  puts state
end

mpd.on(:time) do |elapsed_time, total|
  puts "#{elapsed_time}/#{total}"
end

mpd.connect

while true; end
```

Comment: Did you try `while true; end` ?

Comment: `while true; end` does work, I expected that to block and prevent other threads or procs from running.

Comment: It wastes CPU time, but you could throw a small sleep statement in there to help with that.  It doesn't block other threads, that is one of the main points of having an operating system.

Comment: the MPD object stores the callback thread in an instance variable so I just grabbed that and called join which causes the main thread to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the mpd calls in an eventmachine block, this will handle the `while true; end` loop and not waste cpu cycles. You'll also get all the eventmachine I/O, defer and timer logic thrown in for free?

100% untested code, but it would something like this:

```
require 'ruby-mpd'

EventMachine.run do

  mpd = MPD.new('localhost', '6600', callbacks: true)

  mpd.on(:connection) do
    puts 'connected...'
  end

  mpd.on(:state) do |state|
    puts state
  end

  mpd.on(:time) do |elapsed_time, total|
    puts "#{elapsed_time}/#{total}"
  end

  mpd.connect

end
```